# In a list subclass, how do I assign a list explicitly when creating an instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have a class which inherits from list. How do I assign a list when creating an instance in stead of appending to the instance after creation?
Example code:

```
class ListObject(list):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


premade_normal_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
_list = ListObject(1, 2, 3) # Can I explicitly assign the premade list as this 
                            #  object while retaining attributes?
# How I now have to do it.
premade_normal_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
_list = ListObject(1, 2, 3)
for i in premade_normal_list:
    _list.append(i)
```

I tried this which didn't work to no surprise:

```
class ListObject(list):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, _list):
        self = _list
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

premade_normal_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
_list = ListObject(1, 2, 3, premade_normal_list)
```

I'm having a hard time explaining, hope it's clear enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to call the parent class's `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self, a, b, c, _list):
    super().__init__(_list)
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
```

However, note that this makes certain assumptions about what other classes might inherit from `ListObject` in the future. This definition doesn't accept any other unexpected keyword arguments some other class might require.

Comment: There may be a reason to override `__new__` as well, but I'm not thinking of one.

Answer (score 2):

Or just add an optional arg to your `__init__()`:

```
class ListObject(list):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, premade=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        if premade is not None:
            self.extend(premade)

premade_normal_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
_list = ListObject(1, 2, 3, premade_normal_list)
```

Comment: Would you happen to know which solution is faster?

Comment: I have no idea.